# How can I return a nested subscription?

Tags: angular, observable

I have the following nested subscription that I need the inner subscription returned. How do I go bout doing so?

```
public updateProfiles(){
    this.afAuth.idToken.subscribe(idToken=>{
      return this.httpClient.post<any>('https:example.com/getData',{
        "token": idToken,
        "np":"hzlNpV1239nOKRTcsVdPG",
        "cp":"M6nKYrSjsnA9v34vfB8oD"
      });
    })

  }
```

In the calling module I would like to this.authService.updateProfiles.subscribe(()=>{do something});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make it pipeable.

```
updateProfiles() {
  this.afAuth.idToken.pipe(
    switchMap(idToken => this.httpClient.post(your stuff))
  ).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
}
```